# How to point parent menu item to a link and sub menus too

Tags: navigation

Hi I have a main menu named Home and there a sub menus in it. When I click any of the menu item of sub menu the content of the sub menu displayed. But After that I can not go to home by clicking home menu  as it contains sub menu and it does not point to home link hence its non clickable. My issue is that I want parent item to points to a link and sub menus too. Is it possible?. I am using bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below modules :

1. [Path Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)

> This module is a solution for all problems with the breadcrumbs on
>   your site!
>
> Path Breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for any page
>   with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!

2. [Menu Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb)

> By default, Drupal 6+ use the Navigation menu for the breadcrumb. This
>   module allows you to use the menu the current page belongs to for the
>   breadcrumb.